# How do I add all users with a certain attribute to a group?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Hello friends and neighbors. Active Directory question here.  I've been trying unsuccessfully to use dsquery and dsmod to add all users with a certain attribute to a certain group. No luck so far, as I am not too familiar with the tool or even if this is the best way to handle this task. So let me describe the task first and then hopefully one of you knowledgeable people can help me:

---

1. All faculty members have an employeeStatus attribute set to employeeStatus=faculty
2. I need to make all people with the employeeStatus=faculty be added to a group called all.faculty@domain.com

What's the best way to do this all at once? I feel like I'm missing something really basic here.

Answer (score 3):

This is Powershell.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory # Not needed if using PS v3 or higher
Foreach($_ In Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties EmployeeStatus) 
{
     If($_.EmployeeStatus -Match "faculty")
     {
         Add-ADGroupMember (Get-ADGroup all.faculty) $_.DistinguishedName
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do this through Active Directory Users and Computers GUI. You can view all the users set employeestatus= faculty and then add to the group all.faculty.

To achieve it, you just need to create a Saved Query in Active Directory Users and Computers, Saved queries -> right click -> New -> query -> Click Define query -> Select Custom Search mode -> Advanced -> paste the following query.

"(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(employeestatus=faculty))"

When you run this above saved query in Active Directory Users and Computers console, you will see all the users are listed. Select all the users -> Right click -> Add to group -> Select the group "all.faculty" and click ok.

Now you have achieved what you wanted to do.